# A question about countability of a set of functions from natural numbers to natural numbers

Tags: elementary-set-theory, solution-verification

> Let $\mathscr{A}$ be the set of all functions $f : \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$ such that $\{i \in \mathbb{N} \mid f(i) \neq 1\}$ is finite. Is the set $\mathscr{A}$ finite, countably infinite, or uncountable? Prove your answer.

Let A=$\{i \in \mathbb{N} \mid f(i) \neq 1\}$.

My idea is to find an example. Let A=$\{2,3,4\}$

Then this accords with the requirement that A is a finite set and because all elements in A satisfy the restriction that $f(i)\neq 1$

Then list some suitable functions in all maps from N to N

$ f_1(2)=2, f_2(2)=3,f_3(2)=4,...$

These functions are in $\mathscr{A}$ and they are different functions. There are countably infinite of them.

Similarly

$ f_1'(3)=2, f_2'(3)=3,f_3'(3)=4,...$
Some of the functions in this collection of functions can be the same as the previous collection $ f_1(2)=2, f_2(2)=3,f_3(2)=4,...$, but it doesn't matter because the union of these two collections is also countably finite. Similarly, for 4$\in$ A

As a result, $\mathscr{A}$ is countably finite.

Is this correct?

Comment: Did you proofread before posting? Also, type the problem itself instead of using an image in a link.

Comment: I'm sorry about this, but I actually don't know how to give an image. Every time I paste a image,it will automatically turn into a link which, I know, is inconvenient for readers

Comment: By deleting all your work, you’ve made this a question-only question, and it will likely be closed.

Comment: The reason I delete some is that I find out that I didn't understand the meaning of the question clearly, and now I know my idea is totally wrong.

Comment: I've restored your original explanation of your work.  That's because people here need to see that you tried to work it out on your own.  It's okay if your attempt is off base.  What's important to people here is that you tried.

Comment: Thank you. I will pay attention to this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Choose an enumeration of the finite subsets of $\Bbb N$.  There are countably many such subsets so such an enumeration is possible.

For each finite subset of $S \subseteq \Bbb N$, there are only countably many maps $g: S \to \Bbb N \setminus \{ 1 \}$.  There is a one-to-one correspondence between elements of $\mathscr A$ and ordered pairs $(S, g)$.  There are only countably many possible choices for $S$ and for each $S$ only countably many choices for $g$.  Therefore, there are only countably many such ordered pairs, so $\mathscr A$ is countable.

As noted in Mark Saving's answer, the problem with a diagonal argument is that you haven't proved (and can't prove) that the new function created using the diagonal technique is in fact also in $\mathscr A$ because you haven't proved that it takes on the value $1$ at all but finitely many arguments.

Comment: I can intuitively feel your answer, and kind of have the same idea, but I'm not sure whether I really understand. Also, I update my proof. Could you please check it?

Comment: @Yink You should perform such updates by appending them to the end of your question (and noting that they are an addition to your original post), not by deleting your prior work.  Those deletions make earlier answers incomprehensible.  Your revised proof seems to lack rigor.  You can't "find an example."  You have to prove that $\mathscr A$ is in $1$-$1$ correspondence with some set that you can prove is countable.  The proof really relies on the fact of cardinal arithmetic that $\kappa \times \kappa = \kappa$ for infinite cardinals $\kappa$.

Comment: You are right. I just started to use this website and I don't consider too much and don't know the rules, so I deeply apologize for it. And my idea is that for any element $x$ in A, there can be functions in $\mathscr A$ such that $f_1(x)=2; f_2(x)=3,...$  there is a bijection between natural numbers and these functions in \mathscr A. Thus the collection of these functions is a countably infinite set. Also because A is finite, take the finite union of countably infinite sets is a countably infinite set. Hence the result is countably infinite. Is this reasonable?

Comment: Wouldn't your approach also "prove" that the set of all functions from $\Bbb N$ to $\Bbb N$ is countable?  Of course, that set is uncountable.  That's an indication something is wrong with your reasoning.

Answer (score 1):

It was rather difficult to understand how your "proof" was supposed to go, so I am taking the liberty of rewriting it.

Claim: $\mathscr{A}$ is not countably infinite.

"Proof": Suppose we had some enumeration $\mathscr{A} = \{f_n \mid n \in \mathbb{N}\}$.

We want to pick some $g : \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$ such that for all $i$, $g(i) \neq f_i(i)$. For instance, we could define $g(i) = f_i(i) + 1$.

Note that for all $i$, $g(i) \neq f_i(i)$ and therefore $g \neq f_i$. Therefore, $g \notin \mathscr{A}$. But this is a contradiction. $\square$

What's the issue here? It's the very last line of the proof - "But this is a contradiction". We haven't proved $g \in \mathscr{A}$. So we have in no way established that $g \notin \mathscr{A}$ is a contradiction.

Comment: This set is countable indeed.

Comment: @Crostul Correct - though this needs justification of its own. Just because OP failed to prove $\mathscr{A}$ is uncountable doesn't mean $\mathscr{A}$ is countable after all.